# URL rewriting in ASP.NET turning http://example.com/abcd into http://example.com/page.aspx?id=abcd

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in my web forms ASP.NET app where I would like to rewrite a url from

http://example.com/abcd

into

http://example.com/page.aspx?id=abcd

- the **abcd** part will be unique and I cant create a folder for it
- I want the users to always see the **http://example.com/abcd** url
- would the solution be the same in Windows Azure?

Can somebody please help me with some hints?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.config, in the system.webServer section put something like this:

```
<!-- This has been added to support url rewriting for ... -->
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Page\.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id=([a-zA-Z]+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([a-zA-Z]+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Page.aspx?id={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Please note that I have copied from the config we have in a production site and modified a little bit... needs testing.

The config should work when you have only words ([a-zA-Z]+), change the pattern to make it work for numbers.

hope it helps